# Convert List<Mono<String>> to Flux<String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

There are few question , but there answers are very specific to some code.

Generally, how to convert a Stream of Mono to Flux

```
List<Mono<String> listOfMono = stream()
.map( s -> { do something and return Mono<String> } )
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to convert `listOfMono` object to `Flux<String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [fromIterable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-) and then use [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten the `Mono`

> Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers, then flatten these inner publishers into a single Flux through merging, which allow them to interleave.

```
Flux<String> result = Flux.fromIterable(listOfMono)
            .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

Comment: Is there a inline solution like I can continue the pipeline instead of extracting it to a variable ?

Comment: Before streaming the list ? can you tell me the input collection ? i mean before changing to `Mono<String` @madhairsilence

Answer (score 3):

If your input is a list of Monos you can simply do:

```java
Flux.merge(listOfMono);
```

If your input is stream you can either do

```java
stream()
   .map( s -> { do something and return Mono<String> } )
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Flux::merge));
```

OR

```java
Flux.fromStream(stream())
    .flatMap( s -> { do something and return Mono<String> } )
```

I'd personally prefer the last option as that is the most straighforward and idiomatic.

Comment: Good to know `Flux.merge`

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat too.

```
Flux.concat(listOfMono);
```

In concat, order is always maintained.